# How to find the index of the last element

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have the following code and am using `elementtree`. Each `<product>` has a position index that can be used with other functions. In this instance, the product that contains a Cookie would have a position index of 2.

How can I find the position index of the last `<product>`?

```
<parentelem>
    <project>
        <name>Project Title</name>
    </project>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Biscuit</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Cookie</name>
    </product>
</parentelem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) with the find method:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """<parentelem>
    <project>
        <name>Project Title</name>
    </project>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Biscuit</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Cookie</name>
    </product>
</parentelem>"""

xml_obj = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

print("Nb of elements (children of parentelem): " + str(len(xml_obj)))
print("Count 'product' elements specifically: " + str(len(xml_obj.findall('product'))))
print("Name of last product: " + xml_obj.find('product[last()]/name').text)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this when I'm back at the computer. Will this return the position index, or the object text?

Comment: Oh I was a little too fast answering your question. You can get the last position index by getting the length of `parentelem`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work as it is relying on the XML not having other tags. I did try to modify and use ```print(root.find('product[last()]').index())```, but am receiving an error stating ```'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'index'```

Comment: Doesn't the second print return the number of products? What value do you expect in your updated example?

Comment: It does, but if those products are further down the xml tree then they have different array positions. For example, if I had 10 items before them, and I had 5 <product> tags, then they would be in position 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 repectively. The number of tags doesn't matter, rather just the position of the last tag. By knowing the position the insert statement can insert to position 16 and bump everything in the tree down, keeping the tree structure neat and predictable.

Comment: On another post someone else suggested using lxml with ```insertPosition = int(tree.xpath('count(//product[last()]/preceding-sibling::*)')+1)```, which seems to work. Now it's just other things that I can't get going :p

Comment: I'm lost. What's wrong with `len(xml_obj)` then? It returns the last index and you can insert after that one...?

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit your updated example. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for persisting. I just can't get it to return the right index. All good.